How can I prevent my SOAP request from running multiple times before load on my calculate_shipping function in my custom Woocommerce shipping method?
I have a Wordpress site with Woocommerce.  I'm extending WC_Shipping_Method with a class to create a new shipping method.  I have a calculate_shipping function inside this class; the function instantiates a new SOAP connection and sends a request to a third party service that provides a detailed response with multiple options.  The response time of this service is under 5 seconds when using SoapUI.
When I send the request via the SoapClient in Wordpress it seems to slow the time of the page load from the CART when clicking through to the CHECKOUT to about 15-30 seconds after clicking the "Proceed to checkout" button.  You'll click the button and it seems to send the SOAP request and wait for a response in my calculate_shipping function before even loading the checkout page.
Once the checkout loads, the rates are immediately present in the shipping table however there is the class="blockUI blockOverlay" div over top of the table for another 15-30 seconds while the SOAP request seemingly runs again.
When I remove the SOAP request and add a similar number of add_rate arrays with all of the other logic unchanged, the same process of cart to checkout to page load takes maybe 1-5 seconds at most.  I can add 20 rates and it stays fast.
public function calculate_shipping( $packages = array()) {
    //some logic here to check URI, cart weight, etc. before continuing to customer binding and add_rate
    $newWCShippingMethodGateway = new WC_custom_shipping_method();
    //creating variables from class
    // defining arguments for the soapclient (changed from WSDL_CACHE_NONE to WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY)
    $options = array(
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY,
        'connection_timeout' => 120
    );
    $client = new SoapClient('MY_WSDL_IN_PLUGIN.wsdl', $options);
    //creating the XML document in soapVar to be passed into request
    $soapparameters = new \soapVar("<soap request>", XSD_ANYXML);
    try {
        $result = $client->getRates($soapparameters);
        $numbertoCount = 1;
        while ($numbertoCount < 5) {
            $rate = array(
                'id' => 'demarc'.strval($numbertoCount),
                'label' => 'demarc'.strval($numbertoCount),
                'cost' => $numbertoCount,
            );
            $numbertoCount++;
            $this->add_rate( $rate );
        }
    }
    catch(Throwable $boneThrow){
        echo '<br/>EXCEPT bt <br/>'.$boneThrow;
    }
}

This isn't the code to serve the detailed rates but all the same it's slow just because of the $result = $client->getRates($soapparameters); line; when I comment out "$result = $client->getRates($soapparameters);" the code runs substantially faster.
Things I've tried:

I've tried disabling other plugins thinking it was a bad interaction with our tax plugin or other shipping providers but didn't have any luck.
I've tried only serving one of the multiple rates returned from the SOAP request thinking it was a processing timing issue when using add_rates.  It didn't make a difference and just sending the quote over the client slowed it down.
I've tried changing the SOAP cache type thinking it was an issue with that somehow.  It didn't seem to be.
I've tried changing out, removing, or modifying all of my checks and customer variables to see if that was causing the speed issue.  It hasn't, it's only when I run $result = $client->getRates($soapparameters); - binding the responses and adding the rates doesn't even seem to add any time to page loads or blocks!
I thought it was running two times twice for the longest time (which it seems to be running twice but even then), and that if I added a session variable and bound my results to the session it'd be faster.  I just didn't have any luck with this.

Things I haven't tried:

I haven't used the redis plugin for example to try a different caching method.
I didn't change the way the AJAX is working on the cart because I like the way it functions well enough and that doesn't seem like it would address the SOAP client response time issue.
I haven't changed the way I'm sending my SOAP request (I don't have API key, password, meter number, etc. in the $options array, instead I manually format the request and include those in the .
I saw this thread WooCommerce problems calculate_shipping is called 2 times and didn't try it out - I didn't know where to add their subsequently posted code.

It's my first time posting.  Please let me know if I've broken any rules or if I can cut stuff out.  I don't exactly know where to post this.
Thank you.

do you know in details how the soap cache works ? if the rates doesn't change every minutes, it can be usefull te create your own cache. and then on checkout, the user save the soap call if the code reads rates in the cache.

I don't know in full detail how the SOAP cache works.  I'd imagine I could cache it in the session if the cart contents, token, and destination (I don't know best practice for this) are unchanged but that doesn't solve the painfully long initial quoting times.  Those timings cause a lot of people to bounce.  People tend to change around their cart a lot to see if they can find a cheaper total so there can be lots of different configs that can't be cached because the mileage price changes between quotes.  It's worth looking into; I'm going to focus more on the initial quote for now.  Thank you!
